# What would be the bast way to insert and remove elements of a vector by iterating from the end

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl-algorithm

I'm currently refactoring some really old code and I would like to make it the most C++11 possible ( we don't use C++14 of 17 yet, but it's coming ) mostly as an academic example.

The code is looping from the end of a vector and displaces some of the elements after the current element of the vector.

Here is the code I came up with ( removed a lot of irrelevant parts ):

```
const size_t N = m_ObjVec.size();
size_t idx = N-1;
for ( ; ; )
{
    CObj& curObj = *m_ObjVec[ idx ];

    size_t otherIdx = FindOther( idx, N );

    if ( c_NPOS != otherIdx )
    {
        CObj* pOtherObj = m_ObjVec[ otherIdx ];

        // insert pOther after idx
        m_ObjVec.insert( m_ObjVec.begin()+idx+1, pOtherObj );
        // erase pOther from vector
        m_ObjVec.erase( m_ObjVec.begin()+otherIdx );
    }
    else
    {
        if ( 0 == idx-- ) break;
    }
}
```

I tried using reverse iterators with little success. I cannot use them with the erase / remove_if idiom nor can I use them in a loop where I insert.

What I'd like to write is basically "reverse_move_after_if".

**NOTE** 
It has to loop from the end, only once. Looks a lot like a sort but it's not if you take those contraints into account.

Comment: Are you grouping identical values, so they are adjacent? [1, 3, 2, 1, 3] -> [1, 1, 3, 3, 2]  It looks like your current implementation is worse than std::sort, since you iterate over the vector, and assuming FindOther is O(N).

Comment: You can use std::unordered_multimap as a temp, to rebuild the vector in average O(N) time. It does use a lot of space, though.

Comment: I also notice you didn't check otherIdx == idx, and you erase from earlier in the vector (changing idx but you did that last, so it works out this time). And why does it matter if you loop from the end if you do so much extra work at each position?

Comment: You can assume that FindOther(idx) wont return idx

Comment: Is the objective to write code which a) reverse iterates over the vector in one pass, b) groups like items together, and c) is optimal? So using a temp unordered_multimap is illegal because it loops twice, whereas this O(N^2) is legal? So my std::unordered_multimap would be illegal, but I can store seen values in a set, and just do what you did, but replace FindOthers with a check for "value in set"? Or do you want to impose stipulations against using O(N) additional memory?

Comment: I'm not trying to optimize this piece of code as it has not been identified as a bottle neck. I'm fine with optimizing it but that is not my immediate concern.

Comment: Okay ... important question: Does this code work as is?

Comment: I am trying to find an elegant way for this. The forward version is much more digest

Comment: So you want to wrap that code in a template so it works basically the same as something you get from #include <algorithm>?

Comment: It works, but it smells, I had to write a bunch of automatic tests just to be sure I haven't broken anything.

Comment: I have not been able to make it work with reverse iterators instead of vector indices. I'd be glad to see this

Comment: I'm starting to think that I made this code way too "real" which is in fact pseudo code that does nothing of its own. A lot of people are focusing on the why instead of the how which is not helping at all. I might delete this question and start another one in a few days when I have time.

Comment: Because you specify no jumping around, I assume it must use a one-directional iterator. Consequently, in order to write an std-algorithm-style function, I think it has to write its output to a new container by taking an OutputIterator. It can't do it in place without RandomAccessIterator, and fit std algorithm style, IMHO.

Comment: When I refactor old code, I try to rewrite the code so it does the exact same thins as the original coder wanted but clearer. I'm asking here because I could not find anything clearer and that bugs me.

Comment: @Kenny Ostrom You're right it occured to me that I should just dump the old algorithm and rewrite it entirely with an output containrer. I tried to make it work with a sort but I found out that there was a reason to pass only once and in reverse order while testing it.

Comment: But then I could just use std::transform and swap the output container after... It works but a little disappointing :)

Comment: my point was just that reverse iterators arent "the most C++11" you can get. Wasnt sure if you thought they are new in C++11, for me almost everything in `std` is quite new

Comment: Oh ok I get it, no I mentioned C++11 not to get an answer "at least" C++11 but "at most" :)

Comment: Should I go ahead and attempt it when I get free time? Should be doable since you are allowing an OutputIterator.

Comment: Sure but I don't want you to waste your time. This question is already downvoted so I might remove it before it goes out of hand.